# convert text into an image

Tags: php, image-processing

In php I want to convert a text into an Image. I know that can be achieved by php gd image library. Also there are lots of scripts are available to do this. But I have a different type of requirement. Below I have attached an image. I want that when I will type some text then the text will be convert into an image and the text will be seen as effect which I have attached. So can someone kindly tell me how to do this? Any help and suggestions will be really appreciable. Thanks.

[image]

Comment: including the cords/chains or just the text?

Comment: its difficult to achieve such a fancy text-image design in php. any ways have a look at php GD library

Comment: I want the text effect exactly as refernced not the chains